# Is there something to suppress error in VBA?

Tags: vba

In a Word I am running a macro which triggers Error dialog sometimes. In PHP there I am used to use @command syntax which causes that in case of error the error is not printed to the output. Is there something similar to prevent the VBA debugger stop working?

My code is

```
Documents.Add.Content.Paste
```

and I want to create code, which would test if the result is valid, without breaking the debugger and printing the error, In the case that it failed, I would create timer 1s, and try the command again.

**Edit:**

Current code:

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Documents.Add.Content.Paste
If False Then
ErrHandler:
  ' Add a delay
  Dim tmpStart
  tmpStart = Timer
  Do
    DoEvents
  Loop While (tmpStart + 1) > Timer
  Documents.Add.Content.Paste
End If
```

Currently error happens at line #11: 4605 - property not available because clipboard is empty or damaged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sub-routine or function, insert as the first line:

```
    On Error Resume Next
```

Or if you want to handle the error:

```
    On Error Goto ErrHandler

    If False Then
    ErrHandler:
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Exit Sub ' Or Exit Function
    End If
```

Comment: What is the result of paste method? Is it possible to do something like `result = Documents.Add.Content.Paste;If result = -1 Then ...  `

Comment: you can only assign result to something if the method/subroutine/function you are calling returns something, check the documentation, you could assign result to Content.Paste, but probably not Documents.Add

Comment: Return value of Document.Add is Document

Comment: So what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am testing your code. `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` now errors till now. Thank you.

Comment: Partially yes. New problem arisen. I will ask new question.